# How to write a Procedure with multiple operations like select and update

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Table

```
Id
Count
```

I want to write a procedure to find '`Count`' in the table with '`Id`' as key.After getting '`count`' i have to increment it and update back in the table for that '`Id`'.How can I write this with procedure without using cursors.

I want a simple procedure like below, BUT ITS NOT EXECUTING.IT SAYS PROCEDURE SUCCESSFUL WITH COMPILATION ERRORS.Help me out.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE newpro( inId IN NUMBER, outcount OUT NUMBER) is
select COUNT into outcount from Table1 WHERE ID= inId ;
BEGIN 
outcount := outcount +1; 
update Table1 set COUNT = outcount WHERE ID = inId ; 
END;
```

Comment: Please show us what you got so far.

Comment: above procedure gives an compilation error. Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <een ID>    <een scheidingsteken-ID tussen dubbele aanhalingstekens>    current cursor delete exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "SELECT" to continue. Check the error and correct it. Hint : your code should be between begin and end  tag.

Comment: your life with Oracle will be much easier if you do not use reserved keywords like COUNT in table or column names.  You may find that a sequence will do this job in a less messy fashion. If there are multiple users accessing this procedure the results could not be what you intend.

Comment: Thanks Robert, I put 'begin' before SELECT and its working now thankyou.

Comment: Hi kevin i gave the column name 'count' for example and im not using it in my project. Thankyou

Comment: At what point i should use cursors within procedures, i searched for an examples of procedures without cursors in net, but everywhere i got procedures with cursors only.Why people are using cursors for simple operations i didnt get that.  Though im new to oracle i didnt get the use of cursors.
Please someone help me with this.

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET "Count" = "Count" + 1
WHERE ID = valueHere
```

- [***SEE SQLFiddle Demo***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef616/5)

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
create or replace Procedure Newpro
(
  Inid     in number,
  Outcount out number
) is
begin
  select count + 1
    into Outcount
    from Table1
   where Id = Inid;

  update Table1
     set count = Outcount
   where Id = Inid;   
end;
```